# Use of the word "conversation"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In the dictionary I found that the word *conversation* can either refer to one particular interchange, or to one's general ability to talk to others. In this latter sense, is it possible to use the word *conversation* with an adjective to describe it? For instance, is the following sentence correct?

> You should meet her. She has an interesting conversation.

Or would one of these alternatives be better?

> You should meet her. You would benefit a lot from her conversation.
>
> You should meet her. She has a lot of conversation.

Comment: The first example is non-idiomatic, but I assume it's intended to mean she's likely to converse on *one particular* topic (which is inherently interesting, or which she talks about in an interesting way), OR that she's interesting conversationalist *in general* (even when talking about things which wouldn't normally be thought of as "interesting"). Your alternatives both have different meanings, in that they introduce new concepts - whether the addressee would *benefit* from conversing with her, and how *much* she talks (or how *many* topics she converses on).

Comment: ...we don't usually say *She **has** an interesting conversation* in this context (her conversation is interesting) because it conflicts with the more common usage referring to the *act* of conversing (as opposed to "possessing" the attribute of being an interesting conversationalist). I suggest *You should meet her. Conversation with her is interesting,* but if you want to stick closer to your original syntax, perhaps *She [can] **carry** an interesting conversation* (but some might say that's a somewhat dated/stilted usage today).

Comment: A common way of putting this is  "You should meet her. She always has something interesting to say" - or,  "You should meet her. She always has something interesting to share/going-on/on-her-mind"  ... by suggesting meeting her would expose those things to you, it also suggests she would be fairly open and talkative without mention unless an additional tip to 'ask them about "  was included.

Comment: '_A_ conversation' can only refer to the exchange of talk on a particular occasion - 'We had an interesting conversation'. It would be possible to say 'She makes interesting conversation' when speaking of someone's conversational gifts in general.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you. This dictionary actually says the opposite to your statement: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conversation. One of the definitions is "the ability to talk socially with others".

Comment: I disagree that the dictionary definition is any different from mine. 'Conversation' is 'the ability to talk socially', **a** conversation is a particular exchange of talk.

Answer (score 0):

A noun  to describe a person's gift for conversation could be used. I've heard conversationalist used in that case.

As in: She's a good conversationalist.

Or simply:
She has a gift for conversation?

Comment: A much better alternative. But not an actual answer to OP's question.

Comment: I agree it is not an actual answer to the question, but the question seemed to indirectly ask for alternatives, so I thought it would be nice to suggest a better alternative. I hope that is not inappropriate, I'm a novice on this site, so my form is still a little rough on the edges.